# Minimalistic mysqldump progress bar in bash

Tags: bash, progress-bar, mysql

Hello guys I'm trying to display a simple progress bar for the common user to understand easily at the moment I got this:

```
mysqldump --verbose -uusername -ppassword dbname > dbname$(date +.%d.%m.%y).sql
```

--verbose gives me a lot of information that I do understand but is there a way to show a progress bar that is much easier to read much like wget does:  0%====>====100%   ? or similar to rsyncs --stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well no, because mysqldump does not know how much data it is going to dump, hence it cannot put a percentage on how many was already completed.

You could write your own script that uses mysqldump and imitates a progress bar, updated for example after each database.

Example shell script:

```
databases=(`echo 'show databases;' | mysql | grep -v ^Database$`)
for i in "${databases[@]}";
do
    /usr/bin/mysqldump --add-drop-database --routines --triggers > ~/${i}.sql
    print ".";
done
```

Comment: Ahh I see, would it be possible to do some kind of work-around on that?

Comment: Well you would have to define "progress". First you need to count the *total*, then at certain intervals, you can show the *current*. The problem is that counting the *total* should not be to expensive - an estimate, a number of databases/tables, ... is cheaper than 'the total amount of characters in a dump' because that latter would practically require you to first do a dump to measure that, then do a second dump in which to show the progress. This sample script uses an "update for each database" metric.

Comment: See the problem for me would be dumping twice because the databases I'm working with are over 4GB each, well Thank You for your answer it was very helpful for a beginner like me!

Comment: Well, another option could be not dumping the entire database, but only the DDL statements (create-table etc). Count the amount of create tables, and then do the real mysqldump, piped into a tee then piped into a script. Have the script count the 'create tables' as they pass, and show output on how much passed/how much left. It's just another metric.